# Can I assess my model's performance with LOOCV on the whole dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

Let's say I initially split my dataset into training (80%) and test (20%) sets, perform a 10-fold CV on my training set and obtain an average R² of 75%. After that I check the best model's accuracy on the test set and obtain an R² of 74%, which indicates that the model is fairly robust. Now, before deploying it to real applications, I tune it with the whole data. Someone asks me the model's approximate R²; if I say 74% or 75%, I will me ignoring the fact that the model was now tunned with more data (test set). Is it a resonable approach to perform a leave one out CV on the chosen model with the whole data, compare the predicted targets with the real ones, check the R² (let's say it's 80% now) and say that the real-world model will most likely have an R² of 80%? I see no problems with that, but I do not know if this approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that you should train again on the whole data and it might lead to performance improvements. However, in this context your whole data should not be train + test! It should be just the trainign dataset but without any cross-validation. So before you had %80 for training and you were doing 10 fold CV, meaning that you were training your model actually on %72 of your complete data(train+test) and keeping the %8 for the validation. Now you should train it on the whole %80 percent and report your final results again on the unseen test set.

If you do LOOCV on the train + test, you can not report your performance on validation samples because this is how the model is finetuned and you might as well overfit to validation data.

Comment: I've read somewhere that LOOCV provides unbiased results, therefore if I have, let's say, only 70 samples, is it reasonable to assess the model's performance through LOOCV and explain that a test set was not used since I am dealing with a few data problem?

Comment: My question to you is: If you train 70 times the same model you found in the previous 10 fold CV and you compute the performance on the 1 left out sample. You would average all these 70 test results and compute your performance but then which of these 70 models are you going to report? They all are trained on different data set. Even though there is a high overlap, even one sample can make a difference especially in your case if you have few samples. You are computing the performance of your model but the model itself is different at each time? As far as I know, you have to have a test dataset

Comment: You dont have to use validation set, this also more or less the approach that I defined in my answer. After CV just leave the validation and train it on the whole %80 percent but test set has to be there and I did not see any example of using LOOCV for testing. I hope I could help